# Depth-first search to find the loops in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary set up like this

```
dic3 = {1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 7, 4: 5, 5: 3, 6: 9, 7: 2, 8: None, 9: 8}
```

and I want to find the cycle (if any) on a specified node

For example, if I call `dfs(dic3, 1)` it should return `[2, 4, 5, 3, 7, 2]`

However, I'm not sure why but I am getting a recursive stack overflow and not sure what my error is even though I may be misunderstanding how DFS is implemented? Here is my code:

```
def dfs(g, node):
    seen = []
    if node not in seen:
        seen.append(node)
        for value in g[node]:
            dfs(g, value)
    return seen
```

Comment: This is invalid code; you will get `TypeError` because `g[node]` is an integer and not a list, not a stack overflow. Please make sure your [example] is correct and accurately reflects your problem.

Comment: The error that it gives me first is `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Comment: How do you expect the `if` condition to ever be false, when `seen` is defined as an empty list on the previous line?

Comment: @kaya3 I am not sure how to change the condition since when I was debugging it even though I appended the node to the seen list it would always show as empty on the next call

Comment: where is `value` coming from in `dfs(g, value)` call within the function?

Comment: @JoeFerndz I was thinking of it as each value that is in the given graph at the index of the current specified node

Comment: @Brigitte1Trick, so `g` is the dict being sent, `node` is the value you want to lookup. How do you know when to stop? In your example, key 2 has value 4. So it can go into infinite loop.

Comment: Please, pay attention to your code again. Seems it is not accurate.

Answer (score 2):

`seen` is a local variable; when you recurse, the function starts from scratch. I.e. every time you inspect a new node, your program gets amnesia. Pass `seen` along into the recursion.

As said in comments, the code as posted makes no sense for the given value of `dic3`; if `node` is `1`, then `g[node]` is `2`, and `for value in 2:` is an error, since integers are not iterable. You either need to change the structure of `dic3` to have iterables as values, or the code to not have a loop. If we keep your given value of `dic3`, this works:

```
def dfs(g, node, seen=None):
    if not seen:
        seen = []
    if node not in seen:
        seen.append(node)
        dfs(g, g[node], seen)
    return seen

dfs(dic3, 1)
# => [1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 7]
```

With a different data structure:

```
dic3 = { 1: [2, 3], 2: [4], 3: [4, 1], 4: [] }
```

you keep the loop; but now the path and the seen will differ (as we visit dead ends), so we still need to change the code structure. Since we do not need the order for `seen` any more, I change it to a `set`, a more efficient structure for what it needs to do:

```
def dfs(g, node, seen=None):
    if not seen:
        seen = set()
    if node in seen:
        return []
    seen.add(node)
    for value in g[node]:
        path_forward = dfs(g, value, seen)
        if path_forward is not None:
            return [node] + path_forward

dfs(dic3, 1)
# => [1, 3]
dfs(dic3, 2)
# => None
```

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but to solve the error that you mentioned above what would I have to iterate on the indices for the for loop?

Comment: I am not sure what that seen=None statement means but I am hoping to keep the parameters the same as my original

Comment: It means `seen` is a default parameter, which will have the value of `None` if it is not specified. As shown below the function definition, you would still invoke the function the same way you did before. Since `seen` needs to live between recursions, If you do not use the optional parameter, you would have to either separate the recursing function (with the extra parameter) from the "entry" function (without it), you would have to use a global variable (horror), or define the recursing function as a closure inside the "entry" function.